# Why dir.mkdir() requires no exception handling, when file.createNewFile() does?

Tags: java, file, file-io

Here is a code snippet.

```
File dir = new File("dir");
        dir.mkdir();

        File file = new File(dir,"file.txt");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I want to know why no exception handling is required while `dir.mkdir()` when there is one required while `file.createNewFile()`.

Are we very much sure that "Nothing could wrong" while creating a directory ? If yes, what are the reasons ?

Comment: You're sure that mkdir won't throw IOException because it's contract says it won't.  As for why that is ... *shrug*.  Implemented by different people at different times with different views on what is "exceptional".

Comment: Although I agree this is a poorly designed API, note that there's no assumption that "nothing can go wrong" when you create a directory. You simply need to examine the method's return value. `true` means the directory was created and `false` that it wasn't.

Comment: Because that's the way they wrote it. In about 1995.

Comment: Note that even the old POSIX [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) supports several error codes. Same for `SHCreateDirectoryEx` (including the infamous `ERROR_SUCCESS`). So yeah, not the best design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question.

**There really isn't a good reason for such different behavior.**

The `createNewFile()` was added to JDK in version 1.2 and the `mkdir()` was added in 1.0. That's most likely the reason why API designers decide to make the newer functionality to throw the `IOException`.